# Append the name of each text file to the last line of the file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text

I have ten files: firstFile.txt,...,tenthFile.txt

On the last line of the file I would like to append the name of the file.

i.e. for the first one the last line would be "firstFile"

I would like to perform this action in one line of code

Comment: "Append to the last line" and "the last line would be `firstFile`" are contradictory, unless the last line is empty. What if there is no last line (i.e. the file is initially empty)? Please [edit] and clarify. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Note in Linux `firstFile.txt` is a name, `.txt` is a part of the name (the concept of extensions exists in Windows and maybe in our minds, not in Linux). Still you want `firstFile` in the file, not the *full* name. Right?

Comment: Cross-posted [on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1397424/412264).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bash-4.4$ touch firstFile.txt
bash-4.4$ touch secondfile.txt
bash-4.4$ ls * | while read fn ; do echo "$fn" >>"$fn" ; done
bash-4.4$ cat *
firstFile.txt
secondfile.txt
```

Obviously you may need to change the `*` to suit your particular case.  You might need to consider changing the `ls` for a `find` for more complex cases.

EDIT: If you want to drop the ".txt", then change `echo "$fn"` to `echo "${fn%%.txt}"` in the line above.

(I know `ls *` is odd, but the asterisk acts as a place marker in examples)

Comment: [The mandatory "do not parse `ls`" link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `for fn in *; do …`

Comment: Thank you @Martin!

Comment: @Martin or others, I am then trying to make this into a bash script. At the moment I seem to get an error saying no file or directory. Even though it works fine as a command on its own. Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: Are you aware of using `set -vx` before problematic lines in scripts?  It would mean that you see what BASH reads, and how it interprets it.  However, if you are seeing "no file or directory" the other thing to do is put a `pwd` debugging command just before doing the above.  It sounds as though your working directory is not what you think.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, to add a line with the file's name stripped of its extension (the `r`oot name) to the end of each non-hidden *regular* file (not directories, symlinks, pipes, devices...):

```
for f (*(N.)) print -r - $f:r >> $f
```

With `sh` / `bash` (will also work with `zsh`):

```
for f in *; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && [ ! -L "$f" ] && printf '%s\n' "${f%.*}" >> "$f"
done
```

Note that the exit status of those loop will be the exit status of the last and-or list run in those loops.

To make it so that exit status be only unsuccessful if the script failed to update a file, you'd do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ret=0
for f (*(N.)) print -r - $f:r >> $f || ret=$?
exit $ret
```

Or:

```
#! /bin/sh -
ret=0
for f in *; do
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue
  [ -L "$f" ] && continue
  printf '%s\n' "${f%.*}" >> "$f" || ret="$?"
done
exit "$ret"
```